# In Azure, how to suppress E-Mail-Alerts correctly?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I've established an email alert inside azure. This alert listens to the response times of a specific azue function. If the average response time exceeds a threshold (e.g. 300ms), then the alert will be triggered and an email will be sent. If the average response time falls below the threshold a couple of minutes later, then a second email will be sent ("alert resolved")

Furthermore I established a suppress condition which suppresses the alert at night.

I've noticed that the second resolve-mail will still be sent at night (when the suppress condition is active). The first trigger-mail will not be send at night anymore.

I want that the second resolve-email will also be really suppressed at night. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: How exactly did you configure the suppress condition? And what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to suppress notifications for your alerts would be to use the [Action Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-action-rules) feature, which is currently in ***preview***.

The best part about action rules is that you can define them at any scope: at the subscription, resource group, or individual resource level, with other available filters. While all actions and notifications on the selected scope and filters will be suppressed for the time period configured, alerts will continue to monitor.

As an example, the following action rule is configured to suppress alert notifications from 7 PM - 7AM every day.

[image: Suppress alert notifs]

Please give it a try and see if it fits your need. More about this [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/scale-action-groups-and-suppress-notifications-for-azure-alerts/). Hope this helps!

Comment: How do we see alerts which have been suppressed?

Comment: @johnstaveley If the notification for an alert instance was suppressed, it would be indicated by the **Suppression Status** column in the alerts list. Check this [question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-action-rules?tabs=portal#can-i-see-the-alerts-that-have-been-suppressed-by-an-action-rule) from the FAQ for details.